# Spell check across multiple work sheets in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, spell-check

Im trying to spell check across multiple sheets in excel and I've come across numerous sites that say you can select all worksheets in a doc, then when you use spell check it should check all sheets.

However this doesn't seem to work. I know I have incorrect spellings on other sheets, but it doesn't pick them up, and when doing a spell check on the individual sheet it picks them up.

Any tips to get this to work?

Using Office 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that once you select all sheets, you need to ensure to select all by pressing `Ctrl+A` on one the sheets so all the data gets highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **VBA** macro:

```
Sub SpellChecker()
    Dim s As Worksheet
    For Each s In Worksheets
        s.Cells.CheckSpelling
    Next s
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

You can just Ctrl-click to select multiple sheets (they'll highlight white) and then start your spell check

Comment: This is what I did, it selected all sheets,but did not pick up the majority of spelling mistakes.